# D3 - Positioning tooltip on SVG element not working

Tags: svg, d3.js, position, tooltip

I have a webpage with an SVG. On some of its shapes I need to display a tooltip. However, I can't get the tooltip to appear where it should, just some pixels away from the shape itself.

It appears way on the right hand side of the screen, maybe some 300px away.
 The code I am using to get the coordinates is as follows:

```
d3.select("body")
  .select("svg")
  .select("g")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .on("mouseover", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
  .on("mousemove", function(){

var svgPos = $('svg').offset(),

/*** Tooltip ***/

//This should be the correct one, but is displaying at all working at all.
/*x = svgPos.left + d3.event.target.cx.animVal.value,
y = svgPos.top + d3.event.target.cy.animVal.value;*/


//This displays a tool tip but way much to the left of the screen.
x = svgPos.left + d3.event.target.cx.animVal.value,
y = svgPos.top + d3.event.target.cy.animVal.value;

Tooltip
window.alert("svgPos: "+svgPos+"        top: "+y+"px          left: "+x+"px     "+d3.event.target.cx.animVal.value);


return tooltip.style("top", x+"px").style("left",y+"px");
})
.on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});
```

I got to this code following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190207/how-do-i-get-the-x-y-coordinates-of-the-center-of-the-circle-the-user-mouses-ove).

I have changed $(ev.target).attr(cx) as it is not returning a value on my machine; d3.event.target.cx is, even though it seems it is not affecting the end result anyway.

What am I doing wrong? Could somebody help me please? Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If your tooltip is an HTML element, then you want to position it relative to the page as a whole, not the internal SVG coordinates, so accessing the cx/cy value is just complicating things.  I can't say for sure without looking at your code, but if you have any transforms on your `<svg>` or `<g>` elements, then that could be what's throwing you off.

However, there is a much easier solution.  Just access the mouse event's default `.pageX` and `.pageY` properties, which give the position of the mouse relative to the HTML body, and use these coordinates to position your tooltip div.

Example here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/tPv46/1/

Key code:

```
.on("mousemove", function () {
    //console.log(d3.event);
    return tooltip
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 16) + "px")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 16) + "px");
})
```

Even with rotational transforms on the SVG circles, the mouse knows where it is on the page and the tooltip is positioned accordingly.

There are other ways to do this, including getting a tooltip to show up in a fixed location relative to the circle instead of following the mouse around, but I just checked the examples I was working on and realized they aren't cross-browser compatible, so I'll have to standardize them and get back to you.  In the meantime, I hope this gets you back on track with your project.

### Edit 1

For comparison, here is the same example implemented with both an HTML tooltip (a `<div>` element) and an SVG tooltip (a `<g>` element).

http://fiddle.jshell.net/tPv46/4/

The default mouse event coordinates may be great for positioning HTML elements that are direct children of `<body>`, but they are less useful for positioning SVG elements.  The [`d3.mouse()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_mouse) function calculates the mouse coordinates of the current event relative to a specified SVG element's coordinate system, after all transformations have been applied.  It can therefore be used to get the mouse coordinates in the form we need to position an SVG tooltip.

Key code:

```
.on("mousemove", function () {


    var mouseCoords = d3.mouse(
        SVGtooltip[0][0].parentNode);
    //the d3.mouse() function calculates the mouse
    //position relative to an SVG Element, in that 
    //element's coordinate system 
    //(after transform or viewBox attributes).

    //Because we're using the coordinates to position
    //the SVG tooltip, we want the coordinates to be
    //with respect to that element's parent.
    //SVGtooltip[0][0] accesses the (first and only)
    //selected element from the saved d3 selection object.

    SVGtooltip
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (mouseCoords[0]-30)
                  + "," + (mouseCoords[1]-30) + ")");

    HTMLtooltip
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 16) + "px")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 16) + "px");
})
```

Note that it works even though I've scaled the SVG with a `viewBox` attribute and put the tooltip inside a `<g>` with a transform attribute.

Tested and works in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera (reasonably recent versions) -- although the text in the SVG tooltip might extend past its rectangle depending on your font settings.  One reason to use an HTML tooltip!  Another reason is that it doesn't get cut off by the edge of the SVG.

Leave a comment if you have any bugs in Safari or IE9/10/11.  (IE8 and under are out of luck, since they don't do SVG).

### Edit 2

So what about your original idea, to position the tooltip on the circle itself?  There are definite benefits to being able to position the tip exactly: better layout control, and the text doesn't wiggle around with the mouse.  And most importantly, you can just position it once, on the mouseover event, instead of reacting to every mousemove event.

But to do this, you can no longer just use the mouse position to figure out where to put the tooltip -- you need to figure out the position of the element, which means you have to deal with transformations.  The SVG spec introduces a set of interfaces for [locating SVG elements relative to other parts of the DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable).

For converting between two SVG transformation systems you use `SVGElement.getTransformToElement(SVGElement)`; for converting between an SVG coordinate system and the screen, you use `SVGElement.getScreenCTM()`.  The result are [transformation matrices](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace) from which you can
extract the net horizontal and vertical translation.

The key code for the SVG tooltip is

```
    var tooltipParent = SVGtooltip[0][0].parentNode;
    var matrix = 
            this.getTransformToElement(tooltipParent)
                .translate(+this.getAttribute("cx"),
                     +this.getAttribute("cy"));
    SVGtooltip
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (matrix.e)
                  + "," + (matrix.f - 30) + ")");
```

The key code for the HTML tooltip is

```
    var matrix = this.getScreenCTM()
            .translate(+this.getAttribute("cx"),
                     +this.getAttribute("cy"));

    absoluteHTMLtooltip
        .style("left", 
               (window.pageXOffset + matrix.e) + "px")
        .style("top",
               (window.pageYOffset + matrix.f + 30) + "px");
```

Live example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/tPv46/89/

Again, I'd appreciate a confirmation comment from anyone who can test this in Safari or IE -- or any mobile browser.  I'm pretty sure I've used standard API for everything, but just because the API is standard doesn't mean it's universally implemented!

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work for IE11 :( Great work tho, I guess I have to find a workaround for IE

Comment: Thanks @Johannes. It's been a while since I worked on this. What was the change you made to make it cross-browser?

Comment: No change really, I removed the code that failed :) So the only popop you find in my fiddle is absolute-positioning-HTML over the SVG. The debugger in IE11 made an exception when trying to get one of the parent nodes needed for the other type of popups.

Comment: Ah, yes. IE doesn't support `element.parentElement`, it only supports `element.parentNode`. With that fix it works fine.  I'll update.  Thanks for the check @Johannes!