# D3 (with Bootstrap grid layout) - tooltip placement is off

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, tooltip

I have just implemented a twitter bootstrap grid layout for my page and it works great. The problem is that my tooltip placment is way off. I have gotten it to work by hard-coding some subtractions but that feels wrong.

This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153074/d3-positioning-tooltip-on-svg-element-not-working) deals with it and that was how I thought it should be. But using that leaves me with my tooltip way off my chart area. The code(with my hardcoded values, so this works) is below

```
        divVar .html(formatTime(d.datum) + "<br/>" +"Persons: " + Math.round(d.Prs))  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX-550) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 358) + "px");
```

Why doesn't it work without the subtractions? Here's a fiddle with the simplified bootstrap layout:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/pLcjnno0/2/)

**Update: Element code**

```
var margin = {top: 40, right: 185, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var margin2 = {top: 440, right: 185, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;


var divVar =  d3.select("#chart1")
                    .append("div")
                    .attr("id", "MainTool")
                    .attr("class", "tooltip")
                    .style("opacity", 0);

var divVar2 =  d3.select("#chart1")
                .append("div")
                .attr("id", "AHSTool")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .style("opacity", 0);
```

And some of the css:

```
#MainTool {   
    position: absolute;           
    text-align: center;           
    width: 80px;                  
    height: 28px;                 
    padding: 2px;             
    font: 12px sans-serif;        
    background: lightsteelblue;   
    border: 0px;      
    border-radius: 8px;           
    pointer-events: none;         
}

#AHSTool {   
    position: absolute;           
    text-align: center;           
    width: 80px;                  
    height: 35px;                 
    padding: 2px;             
    font: 12px sans-serif;        
    background: orange;   
    border: 0px;      
    border-radius: 8px;           
    pointer-events: none;         
}
```

Comment: The fiddle you linked to doesn't contain the Javascript.  Where is your `divVar` located?  How is it positioned?  Specifically, if it is absolutely positioned, are there any parent elements with non-default positioning?  If so, then your tooltip would be positioned relative to that parent, not relative to the page.

Comment: Yeah, the js is quite extensive and dependant on data from a database so quite a lot of job setting up a working example. The positioning is absolute on the tooltip but otherwise everything should be relative to the div with id="chart1". @AmeliaBR

Comment: Changing css-position doesn't get any desired effect. It affects the positioning but none of them get close to being the right one. The default position on loading is the one that it should be but somehow it ends up both outside the Bootstrap column and the svg-area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer with better solution than my first.**

My own solution:

```
d3.mouse(d3.event.target)[0] and d3.mouse(d3.event.target)[1]
```

Comment: Not the best way, see @AmeliaBR:s answer as to why.

[Updated fiddle - 19/9](http://jsfiddle.net/pLcjnno0/23/)

**Using AmeliaBr:s suggestion this is what I did(and with updated gridstructure):**

```
.style("left", (d3.event.pageX-document.getElementById('navTopVr1').offsetLeft+2) + "px")         
.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-document.getElementById('navTopVr1').offsetTop-document.getElementById('chartdiv1').offsetTop-28) + "px");
```

The parent-div is chartdiv1(see fiddle for which one). This works better than my own attempt. The -28 is because of aesthetics.

Comment: To clarify for anyone coming across this later: this works because the coordinate system for your SVG is the same as the coordinates for the `<div id="chart1">` that is the reference element for your tooltip div (because the SVG takes up the whole div and you haven't used SVG transformations or viewBox).  Normally, you would need to use `event.pageX - parentDiv.offsetLeft` and similar for the Y position.

Comment: Thanks @AmeliaBR - I'll incorporate it in the answer. I guess that would work for me as well then?

Comment: And id="chart1" didn't work as a reference (or worked, but was off). When I used the bootstrap column div(one level more) it worked better.

Comment: Yes, the "parentDiv" for positioning purposes is the first ancestor that has a non-default value for `position`.  You can give a div `position:relative` (which doesn't change that element's position on it's own) in order to force it to be used as the reference coordinate system for absolutely positioned child elements.

Comment: I change the bootstrap div structure (for better column/row control). But then my offsets didn't work anymore. I have checked every level and there are two different sized offsets, am I right if I subtract them both?